# Delete html element at submit

Tags: javascript

I'm new with JavaScript. Can someone give me an example how to delete an empty form element upon submit?

```
<form action='...' method='post' id='mySubmitForm'>
     <input type='text' name='name'>
     <input type='text' name='email'>
     <input type='text' name='phoneNumber'>
     <input type='submit' value='Save'>
</form>
```

Is there a easy way to check with JavaScript if the form is empty and delete it before submission if so?

Comment: what do you want specifically? do you want to disable the fields that are empty before the form submits? in most cases it makes more sense to figure out if a field is empty AFTER the form submission. with php/asp or what ever server side lang you are using to deal with the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `submit` event that the browser throws before form submission that you can use.

reference: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/forms.html

Return `false` if you don't want the form to be submitted, `true` if you want it to happen. In the event, delete / add the extra inputs that you want accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
function validate(formName)
{
    var form = document.forms[formName];

    //validate, and do stuff

    //remove items that you want with a call like this
    form.removeChild(document.getElementById(id));

    form.submit();
}
```

If this is for validation, you should really be doing validation server side, not client side.

You would call this function like so:

```
<input type=BUTTON onClick="validate('myForm')"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com), which is probably the easiest way.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#.mySubmitForm').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $('input[type=text]').each(function() {
      var inputElement = $(this);

      inputElement.val() == "" ? inputElement.remove() : null;
    });

    $(this).trigger('submit');
  });
});
```

I didn't test that code, but it *should* delete the empty form values before submit, then remove them.

Comment: Why do you `preventDefault()`?

Answer (score 0):

```
function onsubmit() {
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('#mySubmitForm input[type=text]'), function(col) {
        if(col.value=='') col.disabled = 'disabled';
    });
}
```

and `onsubmit="onsubmit()"` in your `<form>` tag

Comment: PS disabling an input is similar to removing it from DOM (i.e disables inputs dont get submitted with the get/post)

Answer (score 0):

Checking through javaScript is easy, but I'd advise you to have-and-assign an `id` attribute to your `form` elements

You can check in the following way,

```
var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
```

and you can remove `email` from your `form` as shown below

```
form.removeChild(document.getElementById('email'));
form.submit();
```

you can have a look at [Adding and Removing HTML elements dynamically with Javascript](http://www.dustindiaz.com/add-and-remove-html-elements-dynamically-with-javascript/) for more details.